# Define MS PowerPoint animation triggers using activeX / matlab

Tags: matlab, powerpoint, activex, presentation

I'm creating PowerPoint presentations programmatically using MATLAB and inserting videos using activeX. However, I then need to manually select each video to set "play with previous" in the animation effects for the videos to play automatically when in presentation mode.

How can I automate this using MATLAB / activeX controls? I have tried searching with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling and playing around, I found a working solution.

**Link to doc for the sequence.addeffect method:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sequence.addeffect

**My implementation:**

```
%Define video animation to play automatically
sequence = slidePage.Timeline.MainSequence;      %get slide animation sequence
vidEffect = sequence.AddEffect(video, 83, 0, 2); %define vid to autoplay
```